# What happens when file_put_content writes to the same file at the same time?

Tags: php

If a script is setup to save text to a given .txt file (file_put_contents) upon pageload, what happens when 2 users loads the page at the exact same time?

Will one of the users (or both) receive an error? Will the .txt file be corrupted? Will the text written to the .txt file be broken? ...or?

I have written a cache function that fetches content from an API and saves it to a .txt file. It writes new data to the .txt file if it has been longer than 3 minutes since last time new data was fetched.
(It decides upon pageload if new data needs to be fetched, or if data from .txt file should be used).

Will this work without problems? Or is there anything I can do to prevent any errors from happening?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking

Comment: Sounds like you'd be interested in the [LOCK_EX flag](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No error will happen, but both processes will write to the file at the same time.
You need to use the `LOCK_EX` flag to ensure that only one process is writing to the file at a time:

```
if (false === file_put_contents('path/to/file', 'data', LOCK_EX)) {
    // Writing to the file failed
}
```

Comment: This seems to be what I need. Thank you!